# Python - Human Like Mouse Behaviour

Tags: python, pyautogui, autopy

I'm trying to simulate human-like mouse movements using `pyautogui` or `autopy`

Do any of you know or can provide a good way?

Let's say I want to move from (0, 0) to (56, 200).
If I use the `pyautogui.moveTo()`, It just jumps there. If I use the `autopy.mouse.smooth_move()`, it does the job but the movement is very fake.

I want it to move to random nodes on the screen but end up on the destination.

Comment: This sounds like a machine learning problem, you should record the mouse behavior during your normal use and then try to simulate it. I don't think there's any readily available package out there for it.

Comment: Have you tried using `pyautogui.moveTo()` to move mouse in small increments towards the target and applying a small random offset to the position?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yah! i am actually experimenting with that right now but the thing is if i put the `pyautogui.moveTo()` in a while loop, it does this very very slowly haha. Its like moving 1 pixel per 0.05 seconds

Comment: @Denise You should provide that code into the question; that might help us figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 7):

`.moveTo()` has two other parameters you can pass to help mimic human behavior, `duration` and `tween`. The first is how long it takes to get to the specified point, the second one changes its behavior such as: start fast and end slow, start slow and end fast etc...

Check out this [section](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#tween-easing-functions) for reference.

I also imported `random` to create a random float to pass for the `duration` parameter, I think it helps make the mouse have more humanlike behavior.

```
from random import *
import pyautogui as py


py.moveTo(720, 360, uniform(0.6, 2.7), py.easeOutQuad)
py.moveTo(450, 900, uniform(0.6, 2.7), py.easeOutBack)
py.moveTo(360, 720, uniform(0.6, 2.7), py.easeInOutQuad)
```

If you are using an IDE, type `pyautogui.ease` (or `py.ease`) and you'll see that popup window which shows you all the variations you can try.

As a side note, human mouse behavior often has a curve to it and `.moveTo()` moves in a linear line. This won't be a problem unless whatever program you're interacting with doesn't want robotic behavior (such as online video games). They could detect that all your movement is linear and then ban your account so be aware (or maybe make your own function that adds a curve to the mouse movement).